# Facebook Graph API Issues Between v11 and v12

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created a php file to post to a page on Facebook.  It works just fine on a different page I have with an app using v11 of the API.  This newest one I created in v12, and used the same code (I did change the Tokens and whatnot to match the new app).  But, I receive the following errors:

**Graph returned an error: (#200) This endpoint is deprecated since the required permission publish_actions is deprecated
Graph returned an error: (#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_posts permission with page token; If posting to a page, requires both pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_posts as an admin with sufficient administrative permission**

Below is the code I have.  I assume that something changed between v11 and v12, but cannot find what to do in the Facebook documentation (I've always had trouble finding what I need with FB documentation).

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '[App ID]',
  'app_secret' => '[App Secret]',
]);

$fb->setDefaultAccessToken('[Access Token]');

$data = [
  'message' => 'Testing 1..2..3..',
  'source' => $fb->fileToUpload('/path/to/file.jpg'),
];

try {
  $response = $fb->post('/me/photos', $data);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

echo 'Photo ID: ' . $graphNode['id'];

?>
```

Comment: Is the access token to a personal profile or a Business Page?

Comment: It's for a page

Comment: Does the token show the `pages_read_engagement` and `pages_manage_posts` scopes if you put it in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/ ?

Comment: Yes, it has both of those listed

Comment: @ceejayoz
Do you have any more insight into why this is happening?

Comment: fb recently introduced the "new Pages experience" - we also had issues with permissions due to that
https://www.facebook.com/business/help/582754542592549?id=418112142508425